# The value of the integral $\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{\sin \left ( e^{\frac{-1}{z}}\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

My Attempt:
  $$\lim _{z \to 0}\frac{1}{\sin \left (  e^{\frac{-1}{z}}\right)} \; does \; not \; exist \;$$

$\Rightarrow z=0 $ is  Essential  Singularity.

But How to compute the value of integral?

Comment: Hint: $\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{\sin e^{-1/z}}\underset{z=1/w}{=}\oint_{|w|=1}\frac{dw}{w^2\sin e^{-w}}$.

Comment: $0$ this is not an isolated singular point. Consider the area outside the circle and a singular point of infinity.

Comment: But limit at 0 does not exist.

Comment: So what type of singularity 0 is..?

Comment: It does not matter, when point not isolated. Solve the equation $\sin(e^{-1/z})=0$ you will see it. It's not isolated singularity and we cannot work with her.

Comment: Why you don't want to work with infinity, there is a disposable singalarity and there is a simple formula for residue.

Comment: So u mean that I should try by replacing z by 1/z and work at infinity..

Comment: No replacing. It's just by definition of residue at infinity, i.e. your integral equals $-2\pi i\text{res}_\infty f(z)$.

Comment: So integral value comes out to be 0 is it ok.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{\sin e^{-\frac{1}{z}}}$, then $\text{res}_\infty f(z)=\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}z(f(\infty)-f(z))$, where $f(\infty)=\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\dfrac{1}{\sin 1}$ (therefore infinity is a removable singular point). So $$\text{res}_\infty f(z)=\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}z\left(\dfrac{1}{\sin 1}-\dfrac{1}{\sin e^{-\frac{1}{z}}}\right)=\dfrac{1}{\sin^21}\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}z(\sin e^{-\frac{1}{z}}-\sin1)=$$$$=\dfrac{1}{\sin^21}\lim\limits_{w\to0}\dfrac{\sin e^{-w}-\sin1}{w}=\dfrac{2}{\sin^21}\lim\limits_{w\to0}\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{e^{-w}-1}{2}\cos\dfrac{e^{-w}+1}{2}}{w}=$$$$=\dfrac{2\cos1}{\sin^21}\lim\limits_{w\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{e^{-w}-1}{2}}{w}=-\dfrac{\cos1}{\sin^21}.$$
And integral equals $2\pi i\cdot\dfrac{\cos1}{\sin^21}$.